# Where can I find the last "eye" to open the red box?

Tags: crimson-room

I just discovery the **Old** game " Crimson Room. and it's not very hard. but the "clicks" are hard to do As @wipqozn said in the [CHAT](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8276160#8276160)

> IT got a lot of hyper about being difficult, but the hitboxes are
>   very, very small, so it's just about clicking every possible pixel
>   until you open something.

This is how I'm atm.

[image]

I believe that is somewhere in this part. It's the only area that I didn't found anything.

[image]

I found the items in those locations:

- CD case (left top drawer)
- Memo (right top drawer)
- Ring (at the bowl near the stereo)
- Cassette tape (below the hack)
- Battery (behind the bed)
- Silver key (window)
- Golden key (below the pillow)
- Metal stick (behind the pillow)
- Power supply cable (left bottom drawer)
- Small box (right bottom drawer)
- Key (inside the stereo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click near the bottom of the curtain in order for the ring to fall out.

Comment: LOL I spam clicks so I could get it done. Thanks. =)